# I am having troubles with creating and executing prototype functions in c++ programming

Tags: c++, function-prototypes

I have started learing c++ programming and am just messing around with different commands and seem to have a hard time using prototype functions and executing them. I am using CodeBlocks for everything. My code is to simply set a password, and have the user enter the password to proceed. Seems simple enough, right? As far as I am right now, this is what I have. (I have not gotten any further in this because I found the error early on)

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// prototype declaration
int getPassword(int nPassword);
// declare combo to be matched
const int nCombo = 3141
int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])
{
    getPassword();
    return 0;
}
// fetch password from user to compare to nCombo
int getPassword(int nPassword)
{
    cout << "Please enter password..." << endl;
    cin  >> nPassword;
    return nPassword;
}
```

When I run this program as is, the cout line does not appear on the screen, the program terminates, and nothing is done. Please help me with this. very frusturating.

Comment: Your function expects an int argument, but you called it without one. Did you mean to use `cin` in `main` and pass that value to `getPassword`?

Comment: As you've pasted it it will not compile not to mention run - you are missing a semicolon after const int nCombo = 3141, and you are calling getPassword(); without the required INT argument.

Comment: `getPassword()` takes an `int` type, you've passed it nothing. I'm surprised it compiled. Further, you immediately overwrite the variable `nPassword` inside the function, before it is used. This makes passing it in by value totally useless.

Comment: Whenever possible instead of using function prototypes reorder your functions so that functions are defined before any line of code that uses the function.  If you have functions that are called in multiple files, you must use function prototypes.  However if the function is only used in the file in which the source code that defines the function exists then it is usually easier to have the function definition and its body before any use of the function so the function definition serves as a prototype.  So move the function `getPassword()` above `main()` and get rid of the prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so there are some issues with your piece of code besides the missing semicolon after you declaration of `nCombi`.

In your declaration and definition of `int getPassword(int)`  you state that the function should take an integer, but you don't provide one when you call the function. Also, the function returns an integer that you don't capture.

I've submitted some fixes below.

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// prototype declaration
int getPassword();

// declare combo to be matched
const int nCombo = 3141;

int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[])
{
    // The main control loop. We continue this forever or until the user submits the correct password
    while (true)
    {
        // Capture input from the user. Save the result in pw
        int pw = getPassword();

        // Here we test if the user has submitted the correct password
        if (nCombo == pw)
        {
            cout << "You got it!" << endl;

            // Break out of the loop, and exit the program
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

// Fetch password from user to compare to nCombo
int getPassword()
{
    int nPassword = 0;

    cout << "Please enter password..." << endl;
    cin  >> nPassword;

    return nPassword;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code is flawless. I can't believe I over looked equating a variable to the return of getPassword(). I still don't quite understand why the cout << "Please enter password..." << endl; would not show up when I executed the program but thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the first thing I saw was that you are passing arguments to your `main` function. This is a no-no as the `main` function is the one that gets called first, and thus there is no way for the program to pass arguments to it. so I'd suggest you change it to simple `int main(){...}`

Next thing would be that you have defined the `getPassword` function to take in an argument `nPassword`, but when you are calling the function, you are not passing any argument, so I'd assume your function`getPassword` doesn't get called. There are two fixes to this :

a) Make `getPassword` accept no arguements.

b) Pass an arguement to `getPassword`. This however, given the way your code is, is not recommend. It seems that `nPassoword` is the variable in which you want to store the user entered password; if you pass it as an arguement, that means you already have the inputted password, and thus it makes no sense to call the function `getPassword` .

So following fix 'a', I'd suggest doing something like :

```
int getPassword(){
    int nPassword;

    std::cout << "Please enter password..." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> nPassword;
    return nPassword;
}
```

and then calling the function by

```
int nPassword;
nPassword = getPassword();
```

The above things in a single code would be like :

```
#include<iostream>

//protoype declaration
int getPassword();

//combo to check for
const int nCombo = 3141;

int main(){
    int nPassword;
    nPassword = getPassword();

    if (nPassword == nCombo)
    {
        std::cout << "Correct password!" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Incorrect password!" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int getPassword(){

    int nPassword;

    std::cout << "Please enter password..." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> nPassword;
    return nPassword;
}
```

Ofcourse, if you want the user to keep entering the password till it is correct, you can just make the contents of the `main` function in a `while loop` which continues till the password entered is correct. Hope this helped.

Comment: No way to pass arguments to `main()`? Are you sure?